# How to hide save option in SharePoint list ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath

I would like to hide a `save option` in `newifs.aspx` page of SharePoint list ribbon.

How to achieve this, I am using `Infopath` Form?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to apply it for all lists add the following style to master page

In case of you need to apply it for specific list

- Add Script Editor
- Add the following style

> ```
>    <style>
>     #Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Commit\.Publish-Large
>
> { display:none !important;   }
>     </style>
> ```

OutPut

[image]

see also the details steps at [Hide a Save button at List Ribbon in SharePoint via CSS or JavaScript](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/12/hide-button-ribbon-list-sharepoint/)

**[Update]**

Regarding adding CSS or JS to InfoPath form it's not applicable , the Infopath forms are not HTML or web pages, they are XML data to be used by external tools.

Read more at [Add js to an InfoPath form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58204/add-js-to-an-infopath-form)

Comment: above style is not working

Comment: In addition, my SharePoint list has been modified by InfoPath

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: M.Qassas, no luck dear

Comment: I am sure it will work try this  <style>
    #Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Commit\.Publish-Large

{ display:none !important;   }
    </style>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43759/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-sam-daniel).

Comment: Sorry, not working!

Comment: Its working for normal SharePoint list but not for InfoPath customized lists!

Comment: M.Qassas, Thanks for your response. FYI I've mention in my second comment. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: NP my bro, you are always welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

add this script

```
var save = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Publish-Large");
save.style.display="none";
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. List item
2. Edit New Item Page
3. Add Script Editor Web Part
4. Add Following Style:

   ```
   <style>a[id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Publish-Large"]{display:none;}</style>
   ```
5. Press Insert Button
6. Click on Stop Editing Page

Answer (score 1):

I just worked on something pretty similar to this. It comes down to permissions. If you want it hidden no matter who is on the page, then @M.Qassas answer would work, but it means you'd need to add that Script Editor web part on every page you want this to happen. Alternatively, you can do this in your masterpage in the section where the PublishingRibbon:PublishingRibbon is:

```
        <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionString="AddAndCustomizePagess">
            <PublishingRibbon:PublishingRibbon runat="server"/> 
        </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

This makes it so only users that have the "AddAndCustomizePages" action can see the edit button (and consequently the Save button). Additionally, this hides the scary options from the Actions menu that you wouldn't want most users seeing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and make sure the CSS is being applied on that page correctly:

```
<style>
#Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Commit.Publish-Large
{
     display:none !important
}
</style>
```

Comment: Its working for normal SharePoint list but not for InfoPath customized lists!