# Hide Commit / Clipboard / Views on SP Form Edit / Submit

Tags: infopath, ribbon

Trying to hide some of the ribbon functions, but not all of them on the top of my form in edit or create mode. Also can I remove the navigation bar on the left while in create / edit?

Cheers, would appreciate as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it by CSS or JavaScript.

**CSS:**

```
<style>
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Commit
{ display:none !important; }
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Clipboard
{ display:none !important; }
</style>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Clipboard").style.display="none";
```

Refer [this](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/12/hide-button-ribbon-list-sharepoint/) for step by step.

If you are using Infopath refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58204/add-js-to-an-infopath-form).